# Calling a Django view using Dajax

Tags: ajax, django, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to both Django and Dajax, but I'm having a problem with a very basic function using Dajax.  Right now, I just want to post a form to Django and return a simple response showing that I reached my endpoint.

However, I keep getting an error returned back to my form.

Here is my form:

```
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}

<html>

    <head>
        {% dajaxice_js_import %}


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function my_js_callback(data){
                alert(data.message);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>  
        <form name="new_scan" action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}                    

            <input type="text" id="scan_sku" name="scan_sku" maxlength="10" />
            <button name="sku_lookup_btn" id="sku_lookup_btn" onclick="Dajaxice.inventory.views.test_ajax(my_js_callback);">Add to order</button>
        </form>     
    </body>

</html>
```

And here is the corresponding view:

```
@dajaxice_register
def test_ajax(request):
    return "Hello World"
```

I'm getting a javascript alert that says, "Something goes wrong"

Unfortunately, I don't know how to debug exactly "what went wrong".

Answer (score 4):

The deal with dajax/dajaxice is: you don't define the dajaxice-callable 'views' in views.py; you create a separate ajax.py file in your app directory, and you define functions in there. These functions look and act a lot like Django view functions -- for example, if you import `login_required` from `django.contrib.auth.decorators`, it'll work on your dajax functions as it does when used on django views.

In fact, here is an ajax.py file that contains a single dajax function of mine, which searches a haystack index to populate a jQuery UI autocomplete field:

```
from dajax.core import Dajax
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_functions
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
import ost2.portfolio.models as ax

def query(request=None, q=''):
    srcher = SearchQuerySet().models(ax.AXItem)
    dajax = Dajax()
    out = []
    valid = set()
    js_callback = "$$('#q')._callback"

    if q:
        results = srcher.autocomplete(everything=q.strip())
        bestmtch = results.best_match().uuid
        for result in results.order_by('order'):
            out.append(dict(
                value=result.title,
                label=result.object.title,
                notes=result.object.notes,
                thumburl=(result.object.keyimage and result.object.keyimage.thumbelina.url or ''),
                urlstring=result.object.urlstring,
                pk=result.object.pk,
                best=bool(bestmtch == result.uuid),
            ))

    dajax.add_data({'data': out, 'term': q}, js_callback)
    return dajax.json()

dajaxice_functions.register(query)
```

... in this case, I am not using `dajaxice_functions.register()` as a decorator -- I developed this function using an earlier version of dajaxice in which you had to register your functions explicitly.

One thing you should note is: the python `Dajax` class instance has a number of methods that map to some action on the client (function calls, DOM manipulation, etc); in order for those methods to properly work on the client side, you set the JavaScript function `Dajax.process()` as the callback (sans parens in your JS code).

Another thing is: I set the default value `request=None` in dajaxice python function, because that makes it much easier to debug. I don't know if you can construct stub requests in unit tests for dajaxice (I don't think you can) but since this particular function doesn't deal with `request`, it can be tested like this:

```
>>> from ost2.portfolio.ajax import query
>>> query(q='yo dogg')
[ ... ]
```

I would recommend that you try something like this after you get your ajax.py file set up, so you can test the python function independently of the JavaScript handlers and whatnot. Dajax and DajaxIce are great in many ways, but unit-test-ability is not one of them.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much for following up. I moved that view function into its own ajax.py file and pointed my js function to the right place.  I also tried your debugging solution by loading it up from the python shell (handy) and that's working fine.  However, I'm still getting that same "Something goes wrong" message.  Any other hunches?  Any way that I can verify that the call is even making it to the server?

Comment: Yeah -- that 'something goes wrong' message is annoying, it was introduced in the most recent version I believe. But yeah -- to verify that you're hitting the server, now that you've tested the function, you can add print or logging functions at the top of your ajax.py function definition. If I recall correctly, I was getting the 'something goes wrong' message when my JavaScript callback was somehow invalid; but because yours is so simple, you might want to make sure your DajaxIce call is valid (e.g. add a '{}' after the callback; inspect the Dajaxice object in FireBug, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

To see what is going on I propose to set up the logging facility for dajax:

Add a file handler in your settings.py under LOGGING

```
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },  
    'logfile': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/path/to/your/log/django.log'
    },  

},
```

As second step add the dajaxice logger to the loggers

```
'loggers': {
   'dajaxice': {
        'handlers': ['logfile'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
   'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
```

If you're working on the console `tail -f django.log` outputs the logs live on the console ...

Comment: Make sure your logfile is writable by the webserver!